# Xamarin Forms on Android: Trouble with shutting down a SSL-Stream and then communicate on the underlying TCP socket

Tags: android, sockets, ssl, xamarin.forms

This is the scenario:
My application currently contains 2 platforms:
Xamarin.Forms.WPF on Windows Desktop (using .NET 5) and Xamarin Forms on Android (10).
The network component is in a .Net Standard 2.1 assembly.
The app communicates with a server process that requires the open TCP connection to be forwarded to a newly created process. This is no problem for the TCP socket itself but not possible for the accompanied SSL-Stream.
So, we must shut down the SSL Stream, transfer the socket to the new process and create a new SSL-Stream.
There is a clear order of messages involved:
| Client | Server |
| ------ | ------ |
| Connect | |
| Initial Communication (TCP) | |
| STARTTLS, Authenticate etc. | Switch to SSL |
| Communicate (SSL)| |
| Shutdown SSL| |
| | Start new process |
| | Transfer Socket |
| | Send “Ready in new process” (TCP) |
| Receive “Ready in new process” (TCP) | |
| STARTTLS, Authenticate etc. | | Switch to SSL |
| Communicate (SSL)| |

The scenario works on Windows Desktop but not on Android and I hope someone might be able to help.
Here is the code that enables the SSL communication:

```
        sslStream = new SslStream(tcpClient.GetStream(),
                                  true,
                                  new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
                                  null);
        // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
        try
        {
            await sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(serverName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcpClient.Close();
            throw;
        }
```

This is used to Shutdown the SSL-Stream:

```
            await sslStream.ShutdownAsync();


            // I discovered that I have to issue a read on Windows Desktop after the Shutdown
            // Otherwise I would get encrypted data in my next Read on the TCP socket
            // This doesn’t work on Android. Regardless of the following Read I always get encrypted 
            // data in my next Read on the TCP socket

            var buf = new byte[128];
            var bytesRead = await sslStream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);

            sslStream.Close();
            sslStream.Dispose();
```

I hope I could explain the problem sufficiently. If I should explain something in more detail, please let me know.
Thanks in advance for any help.
Best Regards
Uwe

Comment: I'm sorry for the garbaged table above. It looks perfect in preview and I do not understand why it's garbled here...

Comment: For this , you can refer to the official document [SslStream Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?view=net-5.0),which includes a sample about how to use the `SslStream` class to communicate with clients.

Comment: Thanks for the link but unfortunately this doesn't apply to the issue here. I have no problem to initiate the SSL communication and I am able to communicate with the server, too.
The problem is that I have to shutdown the SSL stream and use the underlying TCP connection again. That is not working on Android.

Comment: `That is not working on Android.` Is there any logs about this?

Comment: I have modified the DisableSLL() procedure above. It now looks as follows;
`await sslStream.ShutdownAsync();<br>

var buf = new byte[128];

sslStream.Close();
sslStream.Dispose();

var bytesRead = await networkStream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length);`

I receive both on Windows and on Android 31 Bytes in the Read on the networkStream (which is the Stream below the SSL-Stream)
But after that there is the difference between the platforms:
On Windows  I can Read and Write on the NetworkStream without any problem.
On Android the next Read on the NetworkStream hangs and doesn't return

Comment: Is there any logs about this ?

Comment: What type of Logs would you lika to have?